# Stream Twitter by search hashtag and then official twitter stream

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter, twitter-feed

How do I go about calling the twitter API in a way similar to http://socialmedia.duke.edu/#stayconnected

We are looking to do the same type of thing. I cannot figure out what is calling to twitter though in the code.

I can supply any needed details that you would need. I am using Wordpress but just using HTML in a page at this moment.

So how do I see the hashtag searches for said twitter account, and then the actual tweets by said account

Answer (score 6, accepted):

bluedevilsYou just need to use Twitter's free javascript API widget.  It's very easy to use the wizard:
http://twitter.com/goodies/widgets

Here's something similar to Duke's:

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 8,
  interval: 6000,
  width: 700,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#b364b3'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#ffffff',
      links: '#338012'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: true,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().setUser('bluedevils').start();
</script>
```

Comment: Can I assume I just call that script where I want it to show up?

Comment: Exactly.  You can put the first script tag in <head>, but put the second script tag where you want it to appear.  You can adjust the values of width and height to control how it appears.